# Item Description on Paypal Checkout 3rd Party Shopping Cart

Tags: paypal

I'm using a 3rd party shopping cart and i notice that there is no variable for the item description. Any ideas on what variable on how to show or add the item description on the paypal checkout? I already checked  the variables to be used on Passing Individual Items to PayPal. Is there anyway to show the item description using a 3rd party shopping cart? Thanks.

Comment: pls be specific on what shopping cart did you use. 3rd party like Magento has the option of "Transfer line items" in the admin dashboard settings, tick that and it's done

Comment: created my own shopping cart.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Desc">` this is the tag for passing description to PayPal landing page, you may post your payment code in the question for a more detailed answer

Comment: that for the item name. i'm look for the item description. already tried that. thanks.

Comment: Pls see my answewr below and add your comments if any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PayPal Standard Payments (the HTML form button code), there's no tag/variable specific for "description", instead, you would be able to customize your item (besides `item_name`) with the following tags:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Label">
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="Selection Value">
```

The tags set will be displayed on the line item area as `Options: Label: Selection Value` as below

[image]

*If you need the exact "Item Description" field, you would need to integrate with Express Checkout API and work with parameter `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_DESCm`, see further details on the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)*